# Edit an int in actionevent

Tags: java, awt, actionlistener, actionevent

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have an int edited when an action event is performed in Java.  I've been trying to figure this out for days D:.  I've tried to use arrays to do it, but wasn't successful also.

The problem is that the edit int isn't necessarily edited for the whole main method because it's being edit in a separate method.  What I'm trying to do is basically be able to tell if the action performed was actually performed.

If you could tell me a different way to be able to tell if an action has been performed that's better than editing an int than by all means please tell me.

```
oButton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            xButton9.setVisible(false);
            oButton9.setVisible(false);
            nine.repaint();
            nine.add(olabel);
            int x =1;
    }      
} );  

if (x == 1) {
    blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: *"If you could tell me a different way to be able to tell if an action has been performed.."*  Umm.. `System.out.println(..)`, logging, a debugger..  BTW - what is your *question*?

Answer (score 0):

You have to note that after running `oButton9.addActionListener(...)`, the `if` statement will run immediately, so *even if you can* somehow set the `x` from the `actionPerformed`, it would not be useful, because the program flow won't stop at `addActionListener` until the `actionPerformed` is called.

If you're trying to do something when the button is clicked, why just not put it in the `actionPerformed` function?

By the way, you can define the `x` variable as a field in your class, and then:

```
class Test {
    ...
    public int x = 0;

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
        oButton9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Test.this.x = 1;
            }
        });
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't put it in the actionperformed because i have 16 other actionevents and the if statement i want to put in depends on what actions have been performed - not just the the one shown here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the scope of the variable. Your "x" must be an instance variable, then you will be able to use it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing now, is changing the value of the local variable i, you have to declare instance variable in your class and change its value, because only then you will be able to use it in other methods.